# Is this C++ code portable?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, virtual, portability

```
struct A {
  int a;
  virtual void print() {}
};

struct B : A {
  int b;
  virtual void print() {}
};

int main(void)
{
  A *a = new B;
  a[0].print(); // g++, vs2010, clang call B::print.
}
```

All three g++, vs2010, clang call B::print. Almost doubting my C++ 101. I was under the impression that using a dot with an object does not result in a dynamic dispatch. Only -> with a pointer and dot with a reference will result in a dynamic dispatch.

So my question is whether this code is portable?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't a reference work for dynamic dispatch? This has little to do with portability but it is portable.

Comment: virtual dispatch happens via pointers and references.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`a[0]` is the same as `*a`, and that expression is a *reference* to an `A`, and virtual dispatch happens through references just as it does through pointers. `a->print()` and `(*a).print()` are entirely identical.

Comment: You might want to mention that `a[0]` is actually equivalent to `*(a+0)`, which is in turn the same as `(*a)`. That's how array subscripts are evaluated, assuming no operator overloading is taking place.

Comment: @Insilico: No, wait, `a` has a pointer type, and you cannot overload operators for pointers.

Comment: Is there any difference between `A* a = new B;` and `A* a = new B[1];` besides the fact that you use `delete` on the former and `delete[]` on the latter?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I don't think so. The latter returns a pointer to the first (and only) element, and the former just returns a pointer to the object... looks like they're pretty much the same (assuming no hocus pocus in the underlying allocation functions).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: True, but what I meant was that if `a` wasn't a pointer type but was a `std::vector<A>` instead, then `a[0].print();` would not equivalent to `*(a).print();`, but to `a.operator[](0).print();`

Comment: @Insilico: That's true. And if this weren't C++ but CSS, then `a[href]` would be an element selector, while `*a` would match all anchors.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: there is a chance that `new A[1]` allocates memory for an extra word to have access to the number of elements which need to be destroyed. Also, although not use in this example the non-array form allow specifying the constructor to be called.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: No doubt that the memory requirements of the two forms differ, but I think we knew that. Good point about the constructor, though, but you can write `new A[1] { A(...) };` if you like, or `new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };`.

Answer (score 4):

It's portable.  a[0] returns a reference, and references use dynamic dispatch as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is equivalent to -

```
a->print();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is portable and the behaviour is well-defined. `operator[]` on a pointer just does pointer arithmetic and a dereference. It is adding `0 * sizeof(A)` to the pointer, so in a sense it is a "dangerous" operation as any other value but 0 would fail (on an array of Bs), but as 0 * sizeof(A) is 0, in this case you're ok because it's adding 0.

Polymorphism works on references as well as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `a[0]` with a pointer is well defined and means the same as `*(a + 0)`. That's how the built in `[]` operator works.

You are partly right about the compiler not *needing* to use dynamic dispatch when there is no polymorphism. This is just a common optimization though, and not required by the language.

When the code is

```
A a;
a.print();
```

the compiler can call the correct function directly, because it can tell the object type at compile time.

Comment: I'm (sort of) curious about one thing.  I can't imagine an implementation where it wouldn't work, but `a[0]` is `*(a+0)`; there's pointer arithmetic in there.  And I think that pointer arithmetic is undefined behavior if the dynamic type of the pointed to object is different from the static type, which is the case here.

Comment: True (sort of), but I have a hard time seeing that `a + 0` could be different from `a`. Probably not mentioned in the standard. :-)

Comment: On the other hand, I wouldn't expect the rules concerning `a + 0` to differ from those concerning `a + 1`:-).  (I don't like special cases.)  In practice, of course, `a + 0` is required to be equal to `a` when there's no undefined behavior, and I can't see an implementation making it different when there theoretically is undefined behavior.